# Android notification click doesn't work when running the app from notification

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

My app receive FCM and show as notification. So I create the notification like this:

```
    val notificationManager = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

    /**
     * Notification Channel
     */
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(id, "Notification", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
        notificationChannel.description = "This is notification channel"
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true)
        notificationChannel.lightColor = Color.RED
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true)
        notificationChannel.vibrationPattern = longArrayOf(0, 1000, 500, 500)

        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
    }

    val messageNotification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, id)
        .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_delivery_dining_24)
        .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
        .setContentTitle("${getString(R.string.new_orders)} ${tableNumber}")
        .setContentText("${orderNumber} ${name}")

    /**
     * Main Notification
     */
    val summaryNotification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, id)
        .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
        .setStyle(
            NotificationCompat.InboxStyle()
                .setSummaryText("Incoming orders")
        )
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_delivery_dining_24)
        .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
        .setContentTitle("${getString(R.string.new_orders)} ${tableNumber}")
        .setContentText("${orderNumber} ${name}")

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        summaryNotification.setGroup(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID)
        messageNotification.setGroup(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID)
        summaryNotification.setGroupSummary(true)
    }

    notificationManager.notify(value, messageNotification.build())
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        notificationManager.notify(1, summaryNotification.build())
```

I set the `PendingIntent` like this:

```
val resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        this,
        intent = Intent(this, NotificationActivity::class.java).apply {
            putExtra(ORDER_ID, message.data["id"])
        },
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT or PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE
    )
```

The `manifest.xml` like this:

```
<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyStyle">
    ...

    <service
        android:name=".service.NotificationMessage"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/logo_icon" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />
</application>
```

When I open the app normally, every time I click the incoming notification. it's always work as expected. The app will go to my `NotificationActivity`.

But when my app doesn't opened, then I click the incoming notification. The app will running, then go to `NotificationActivity` directly. after that, when the next notification incoming, nothing to happen when I click. just disappear after clicked.

**How to getting the notification click to work every time when I run the app from notification?**

Comment: `notificationManager.notify(1, summaryNotification.build())` why do you always use the same notification ID of 1?

Comment: I create grouped notification, So i need single id to load any grouped.